# Find max value in a column

Tags: postgresql

I created a few databases and now trying to write a request to find events name, their organizers and the number of sold tickets (There are tables "Organizers", "Events", "Tickets"):

```
SELECT "Organizers".name, "Events".name, COUNT("Tickets".ID) as tickets_count FROM "Events"
INNER JOIN "Organizers" on "Events".organizer_ID = "Organizers".ID
INNER JOIN "Tickets" on "Events".ID = "Tickets".event_ID
GROUP BY "Organizers".name, "Events".name;
```

I've got this result:

[image]

But I don't know how to output only events with max tickets_count. Does somebody know how to do it?

Comment: Have you tried with `HAVING tickets_count = ( SELECT COUNT("Tickets".ID) as tickets_count  ... ORDER BY tickets_count DESC LIMIT 1)`? Maybe a bit messy though.

Comment: Add script for create table, sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In recent (starting with v13) versions of PostgreSQL, just add to the end

```
order by tickets_count DESC fetch first 1 row with ties;
```